# Visiting Child nodes of all array element

Tags: swift, data-structures

I have an array of objects with following object. It contains child property that is actually another array of objects with same type and this structure goes on.
What i actually want now is i want to visit all Childs for all elements in array.

```
  class Group
    {
        var groupinfo:NSDictionary?
        var groupBalanceInfo:NSDictionary?
        var collapsed=true
        var haveChilds=false
        var groupHieght=30.0
        var child:Any?
        var level:Int?
        var queryString:String?
        var parentIndex = [Int]()
        var index = 0
    }
```

I am trying to find Count of all childs and sub childs, i have tried following  but it seems to be not working.

```
func calculateCount()->Int
   {
   var allElementCount = 0
        var groups = agBalances.groups!
        for loop  in groups
        {
            if loop.child != nil
            {
                groups = loop.child as! [Group]
                allElementCount=allElementCount+groups.count
                continue
            }
        }
        return allElementCount
    }
```

Comment: If `child` is an  *array of objects with same type* why is it `Any` and not `[Group]`? And don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift.

Comment: okay i will remove NSDictionary and  replace any to [Group]? , whats next ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a tree you need a recursive function which calls itself.

I recommend to declare the *children* as non-optional empty array rather than a singular name (*child*) and unspecified `Any?`

```
var children = [Group]()
```

The recursive function takes two `inout` parameters, the counter and the (sub-)group.

```
func calculate(count: inout Int, in group: inout [Group])
{
    if !group.isEmpty {
        count += group.count
        for child in group {
            calculate(count: &count, in: &child.children)
        }
    }
}
```

and call it

```
var groups = agBalances.groups!
var groupCount = 0

calculate(count: &groupCount, in: &groups)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is method to get count of all childs and sub childs based on your `Group` model

```
var count = 0
func getCount(groups: [Group]) -> Int {
    for group in groups {
        count += 1
        // recursive call of function for child
        if let child = group.child as? [Group] {
            getCount(groups: child)
        }
    }
    return count }
```

Comment: it will not work as we structure can go to 100 times nested structure.

Comment: what does "as we structure can go to 100 times nested structure" mean? Probably you suppose that child can also have child, right? Then you want to get count of all children, recursively. Did I understand you correctly? P.S. For now, I wrote method based on one you proposed in your question.

Comment: yes now it can work but i have posted the answer already i done that one . thanks for giving you precious time.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how i solve it using recursion

```
  func calculateCount(groups:[Group])->Int
    {
        countElements=0
        var allElementCount = 0
        var groups = agBalances.group!
        for loop  in groups
        {
            allElementCount = search(childrens: loop)
            print("Printing Count: \(allElementCount)")
        }
        return allElementCount
    }
func search(childrens: Group) -> Int {
    if childrens.child != nil
    {
        countElements=countElements+(childrens.child?.count)!
        for child in childrens.child! {
        let result = search(childrens: child)
        }
    }
    return countElements
}
```

}